# Speed device is not been applying

Tags: android, performance, accelerometer, sensors

I´ve searching ways to calculate the speed of an android device. I found something, but even though I couldn´t solve it.

I´m applying the formule V = Vo + a*t to calculate the speed, and using the TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELEROMETER. Nonetheless I don´t get coherent results I don´t know why.
If i move the device toward the right the axis X dont grow up, and if i do toward the left, it doesn´t neither. Idem for up and down. Even when it´s stopped there are variations (not g!!, but others).

Here it´s my code commented. If someone can help I'd be thankful =)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener, OnClickListener {

    TextView txtGravity,txtMax;
    Button btnStart;

    private long previousMarkTime;
    private Vector currentSpeed;

    private Boolean measure;

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mSensor;


    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        measure = false;

        txtGravity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txtMax = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(this);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent a) {
        if(previousMarkTime==0){
                        // I get the first time
            previousMarkTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
            return;
        }

        long current_time= System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Here I calculate the diference between now and the previous time
        long t = current_time- previousMarkTime;

        // I create a vector to store the acceleration
        Vector aceleracionPorT = new Vector(a.values[0], a.values[1], a.values[2]);
        double t_f = (float)t;

        // This is   a*t
        aceleracionPorT.doMultiplyScalar(t_f/1000);

        // and this is    Vo + a*t
        currentSpeed.sum(aceleracionPorT);


        previousMarkTime = t_actual;

        // I show the results
        txtGravity.setText(currentSpeed.toString("0.000") + "\n"+
                           aceleracionPorT.toString("0.000"));

    }
    @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        measure = false;
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
      }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View id) {
        if(id==btnStart){
            measure = !measure;
            if(measure) {
                mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
                currentSpeed = new Vector(0,0,0);
                previousMarkTime = 0;
            }
            else txtGravity.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply the formula you need a constant acceleration or you need to know the average acceleration over the period of time between sensor readings.   The sensor in your phone gives you the instantaneous acceleration, but it does not integrate that value over time, so this technique is unlikely to generate accurate speed values.

The other effect you are seeing -- changing values when the device is stationary -- may well be the normal noise in real-world sensors.  They rarely behave exactly the way they theory says they should, so the signals need to be conditioned (smoothed, scaled, calibrated, etc.)